# Starting Command for Powershell 7 in Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I would like to start Powershell 7 in Windows Terminal with a Command:

```
npm run start
```

So I configured it like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Command "npm start run"
```

However, when starting it, I am getting this error:

```
> ng serve --port 7331 run
Error: Unknown argument: port
[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

I am confused because it is **starting the correct command**, but then has a problem with its internal parameter.

Do I have to escape something, or what am I missing?

Comment: See if any solutions in answers here help with this problem just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335300/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda ... but specifically `C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f`